# EWS set mail item body HTML

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

We are developing an add-in for the Outlook web app.

Using the [UpdateItem operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/updateitem-operation) we are able to set a mail item body (in read mode) via an EWS SOAP request using `mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync`.

Setting a mail item body is possible using plain `Text` or `HTML`.
However, when choosing `HTML`, it is unclear:

- which tags are supported,
- if and what encoding needs to be used

We are using Angulars [DomSanitizer.sanitize()](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) to sanitize HTML before adding it to the SOAP body that is sent.

The request completes with statuscode `200` and ResponseCode `NoError`.

Below is the copied request from Chrome DevTools, whereby only the `Token` value was replaced.

```
{
"__type":"EwsProxyRequestParameters:#Exchange",
"Body":"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <soap:Envelope
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
        xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'
        xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
        xmlns:t='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'>
        <soap:Header>
          <t:RequestServerVersion
            Version='Exchange2013'
            xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'
            soap:mustUnderstand='0'/>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
        <UpdateItem MessageDisposition='SaveOnly' ConflictResolution='AutoResolve'
          xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'>
        <ItemChanges>
          <t:ItemChange>
            <t:ItemId Id='AAMkAGMwZjFmZmM2LThiMjgtNGRmMS04MmU2LTVkMThkMzFiYzIyMQBGAAAAAACZUf7WM06iT6k1a2RX1stKBwB2lPdRh025RIK1EWGYTEUEAAAAAAEMAAB2lPdRh025RIK1EWGYTEUEAAGcC958AAA=' ChangeKey='CQAAABYAAAB2lPdRh025RIK1EWGYTEUEAAGcFNmY'/>
            <t:Updates>
              <t:SetItemField>
                <t:FieldURI FieldURI='item:Body'/>
                <t:Message>
                  <t:Body BodyType='HTML'>Lorizzle ipsum dolor stuff amizzle, hizzle adipiscing dawg. Nullizzle sapien velizzle,&#10;    check out this volutpizzle, nizzle quizzle, gravida vizzle, shiz. The bizzle eget tortor.&#10;    Sed erizzle. Fusce izzle da bomb break yo neck, yall bizzle tempizzle gizzle.&#10;    Maurizzle pellentesque nibh break it down turpizzle.&#10;    Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle tortizzle. Fizzle eleifend rhoncizzle phat.&#10;    Away hac habitasse platea dictumst.&#10;    Donec we gonna chung. Curabitur mofo urna, pretizzle shizznit, mattis ac, eleifend vitae, nunc.&#10;    Rizzle suscipizzle. My shizz sempizzle velit sizzle purizzle.</t:Body>
                </t:Message>
              </t:SetItemField>
            </t:Updates>
          </t:ItemChange>
        </ItemChanges>
      </UpdateItem>
     </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>",
"Token":"long-token-hash",
"ExtensionId":"e2dbabaf-01ec-40f9-8cf8-700586930909"
}
```

Using HTML outputted by OWA itself when composing an HTML message renders nothing. but also a simple piece of text wrapped in `<span>text</span>` does not render anything, already.

What are we missing to make OWA correctly render HTML email bodies ?